# How can I convert native PHP7 into query eloquent Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-server-2012

I'm migrating from php 7 to laravel and am having trouble completing the query. how to solve data query like the example below

$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

```
select id, tglupload, 
substring(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2) date, 
COUNT(1) as Totalemployeall
from [MS_SK] 
where substring(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2) = $month
and substring(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),7,4) = $year
AND (status_allow <> 'NOTALLOW' OR status_allow is null)
GROUP BY rollup(id, tglupload)
order by id ASC
```

Comment: Why not using raw query in laravel for this?

Comment: yes, it can. I just want the usage to be uniform using the eloquent query..

Comment: Using raw queries is uniform, there is no must to use the active model - sometimes it is better to use raw queries. IMO in your case you should use raw queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to use a raw query for that. But you can make your query nicer using the [Laravel's scope function](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes).

For example in your model (the model related with the table `[MS_SK]`) you can add the following 2 scope functions:

```php
class YourModel extends Model {

    public function scopeFiltrateTglUpload($query, int $month=null, int $year=null)
    {
        $year = $year ?? date('Y');
        $month = $month ?? date('m');

        return $query->where(\DB::raw("substring(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2)", "=", $month))
            ->where(\DB::raw("substring(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),7,4)", "=", $year));
    }

    public function scopeTheStatusIsNullOrNotAllowed($query)
    {
        return $query->where(function($subQuery) {
            $subQuery->where('status_allow', '<>', 'NOTALLOW')
                ->orWhereNull('status_allow');
        });
    }

}
```

Then you can use them as per below:

```php
$result = YourModel::selectRaw('
        `id`, `tglupload`, 
        substring(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2) `date`, 
        COUNT(1) as `Totalemployeall`
    ')
    ->filtrateTglUpload()
    ->theStatusIsNullOrNotAllowed()
    ->groupBy(\Db::raw('rollup(id, tglupload)'))
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->get();
```

Please note that this is just an example to give you an idea. Then you should make it work :) Please tell me in the comment if you need any help.

Comment: i have followed the function that is in the model, but the query result is getting:

select id, tglupload, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2) "date", COUNT(1) as "Totalemployeall" from [MS_SK] where SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2) = 02 is null and SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),7,4) = 2022 is null and ([status_allow] <> NOTALLOW or [status_allow] is null) group by rollup(id, tglupload) order by [id] asc
how to cast is null in query
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2) = 02 is null and SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),7,4) = 2022 is null

Comment: I just updated the scope function `scopeFiltrateTglUpload`. Please try it to see if it works now.

Comment: still not what you want. i mean disappear is null but filled with current month like this month feb = 02
like this
substring(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2) = 02
no
substring(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2) is null

Comment: it worked, I changed the scopeFiltrateTglUpload like this:

Comment: public function scopeFiltrateTglUpload($query)
    {
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');

        return $query->whereRaw("SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),4,2) = $month")
            ->whereRaw("SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,tglupload,106),7,4) = $year");
    }

    public function scopeTheStatusIsNullOrNotAllowed($query)
    {
        return $query->where(function($subQuery) {
            $subQuery->where('status_allow', '<>', "'NOTALLOW'")
                ->orWhereNull('status_allow');
        });
    }

Comment: thank you for helping me..